# How to Wait for an Exit Event of a Window?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have this code for a Button:

```
private void createDeleteButton() {
    Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");

    deleteButton.addClickListener((Button.ClickEvent e) -> {
        LOG.info("Creating DeleteModal Window");
        DeleteModal deleteModal= new DeleteModal(queryName);
        this.getUI().getUI().addWindow(deleteModal);
        // I want to wait for the exit event of delete modal
        // and then execute the next method
        refresh();
    });
    buttonPanel.addComponent(deleteButton);
}
```

When I click this button a window appears, but at the same time the `refresh();` method is executed

Are there some way to wait for the exit event of `deleteModal` and then execute the `refresh();` method?

Notes:

DeleteModal `extends Window`

I'm Using Vaadin

The class that contains this method `extends VerticalLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to window's close event with [`Window.addCloseListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html#addCloseListener-com.vaadin.ui.Window.CloseListener-).

Something like this should work (DISCLAIMER: untested code):

```
deleteModal.addCloseListener((Window.CloseEvent e) -> refresh());
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, It's what I was looking for